# Run docker postrgessql image twice first exits

Tags: postgresql, docker

I made 2 yml and when i run *docker-compose -f postgresql.yml up*  its starts ok
and then when i run *docker-compose -f postgresql2.yml up* first exist code 0.
Is it even possible to run same image twice?
My main purpose to run same web app source twice with different db on the same server pc.
1 web app source 2 instances with self db each on one server(maybe its clearer definition).
Maybe there is better approach and I do and think everything in wrong way.

```
# This configuration is intended for development purpose, it's **your** responsibility to harden it for production
version: '3.8'
services:
  freshhipster-postgresql:
    image: postgres:13.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=FreshHipster
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

and this no big difference
postgresql2.yml

```
# This configuration is intended for development purpose, it's **your** responsibility to harden it for production
version: '3.8'
services:
  freshhipster-postgresql:
    image: postgres:13.1
    container_name: postgres2
    volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data_vol2/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=FreshHipster
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
volumes:
    pgdata:
        external: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another service name `freshhipster-postgresql2` on postgresql2.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  freshhipster-postgresql2:
    image: postgres:13.1
    container_name: postgres2
    volumes:
        - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data_vol2/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=FreshHipster
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    # If you want to expose these ports outside your dev PC,
    # remove the "127.0.0.1:" prefix
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
volumes:
    pgdata:
        external: true
```